# SQL Server Create multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

The table contains a PRIMARY KEY column and another column which is FOREIGN KEY. This works fine. When I attempt to add another column as a FOREIGN KEY I get the following message:

[Link to pic](http://twitpic.com/15zemj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to the PKs or FKs.

There is a setting in SQL Server 2008 SSSM to prevent table rebuilds via the designer.

Tools..Options..Designers... clear the option “Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation”.